# Load Saved strings from Isolated Storage in ObservableCollection with For Loop

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

Im playing around with the Isolated Storage, i want to Load saved strings from a txt file into my ObservableCollection List with a for Loop!

It Works good if i load more than 3 saved Items but when i Load just 1 item it doesnt Load it correct!

Maybe someone have a Idea.

This is what i tried yet:

```
private void ReadDrinkInformation()
        {
            try {

                // Variabels to load the Drink Information
                string _loadedDrinkName = null;
                string _loadedPreisDrink = null;
                string _loadedCountDrink = null;
                string _loadedBottleDrink = null;

                var checkDrinkDirFiles = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

                // Not important just a String for Path
                string currentProfile = Functions.GetCurrentProfileLoggedIn();

                // Not important just a String for Path
                string currentEntwurf = Functions.GetCurrentEntwurfLoggedIn();

                string[] checkedDir = checkDrinkDirFiles.GetDirectoryNames();
                List<string> drinksSpace = new List<string>();

                foreach( var dirs in checkedDir ) {

                    if( dirs.Contains("CurrentProfileUser_" + currentProfile + currentEntwurf + "_Bier") ) {

                        // List the Files with the SearchPattern
                        string searchPattern = "CurrentProfileUser_" + currentProfile + currentEntwurf + "_Bier\\*";
                        string[] checkedFiles = checkDrinkDirFiles.GetFileNames(searchPattern);

                        // Loop through listed File  
                        for( int i = 0; i < checkedFiles.Length; i++ ) {

                            // Get Saved Drinks 
                            drinksSpace = Drinks.ReadDrinkInformation(checkedFiles[i], "Bier");

                            for( int j = 0; j < drinksSpace.Count; j++ ) {

                                if( drinksSpace[j].StartsWith("Name:") ) {

                                    _loadedDrinkName = drinksSpace[j].Replace("Name:", string.Empty);
                                }

                                if( drinksSpace[j].StartsWith("Preis:") ) {

                                    _loadedPreisDrink = drinksSpace[j].Replace("Preis:", string.Empty);
                                }

                                if( drinksSpace[j].StartsWith("Art:") ) {

                                    _loadedCountDrink = drinksSpace[j].Replace("Art:", string.Empty);
                                }

                                if( drinksSpace[j].StartsWith("Wich:") ) {

                                    _loadedBottleDrink = drinksSpace[j].Replace("Wich:", string.Empty);
                                }


                                if( j == checkedFiles.Length - 1 ) {

                                    _beerDrinkList.Add(new BierAuswahl {
                                        _DrinkName = _loadedDrinkName,
                                        _DrinkAmount = _loadedPreisDrink,
                                        _DrinkBottle = _loadedBottleDrink, 
                                        _DrinkCount = _loadedRechnungsArtDrink
                                    });

                                    this.lstDrinks.ItemsSource = _DrinkList;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {

                        drinksSpace = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch( Exception ex ) {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Information", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
        }
}
```

So if i Load just One Text File then just the _DrinkName is displayed. If I load more then 2 TextFiles it works Fine. I guess something with the for loop is wrong, but i cant find the reason.

Thanks for your Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem to me that `if( j == checkedFiles.Length - 1 ) {` should be `if( j == drinksSpace.Length - 1 ) {`

Comment: Agreed. That seems to be the source of your specified issue. I'd also recommend moving "this.lstDrinks.ItemsSource = _DrinkList;" outside of the if-statement and for-loop and have it as a statement that executes once the prior operations complete.

Comment: Yeah Thanks guys for the answer ! Thats the Solution ! Ive tried so much :) the answer is simple :)